# Http GET requests over one tls connection using Go

Tags: go

Currently, I am using http GET requests to connect to a server.
`Get` request is calling from inside a thread. For each `Get` request one thread is being used but problem is for each `Get` request, one connection is established. Thus if there are 10000 `Get` request then 10000 connections will be established. However, I want first to establishe a TLS connection between me and the server, then create a thread and from that thread I want to send `Get` over that already established connection.

e.g.

```
for {
    1. establish a tls connection
    2. create thread go func()
}

func() {
    resp, err := http.Get(url) // should be over already established tls connection
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, just to clarify, Go has **goroutines**, not threads. Goroutines are co-operative light-weight processes. The Go runtime time-slices a number of goroutines onto the available operating system threads. This thread abstraction is an important feature of Go.

On the question of making many concurrent GET requests using goroutines, it is best initially to let the standard API handle multiplexing of requests onto connections for you. There may be a large number of requests and a smaller number of supporting connections. Provided you use keep-alive connections, you should not need to care about the details.

For control over proxies, TLS configuration, keep-alives, compression, and other settings, [create a Transport](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

HTTP/1.1 handles keep-alive connections with both http and https. This is a benefit when many requests are made to the same server. As long as you *don't* force it to close each connection after each request, you will get a lot of benefit from keep-alive connections in your case.

The usual mantra applies: don't optimise prematurely. Describe what you need to do as clearly as possible. Benchmark it (Go has a useful micro-benchmark tool). Do this before you decide whether or how to optimise the performance.

Comment: Thanks Rick for your support but my concern is is it possible only one connection and multiple request over the same connection? If not what is the other way to do the same in Go?

Comment: Each [Transport](http://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go) instance has a pool of connections. The http [Client](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) that uses a given Transport will make use of these connections for its requests. So in the first instance, assume that the standard API will work very efficiently and you don't need to worry about connections and pooling. Only after you've tried this, measured it and found it too slow should you start looking for implementation alternatives.